# Appcelerator open/read email attachment into my app - Android

Tags: android-intent, appcelerator, titanium-mobile, intentfilter

I am trying to open a custom file type from email attachment into my app. I am using intent filter for open my app when custom file was clicked. Here is my intent filter.

```
<intent-filter>
            <data android:scheme="content" />
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
            <data android:mimeType="application/*" />
            <data android:pathPattern=".*\\.asd" />
        </intent-filter>
```

But now I need to read the attach file. I did not find any documentation for it. Can anybody help me.

Note: For Iphone I used **Ti.App.getArguments()** which returns file-system directory of email attachment.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You need to provide [`BroadcastReceiver`](http://docs.appcelerator.com/titanium/latest/#!/api/Titanium.Android.BroadcastReceiver) for the intents to handle this in your app.

```
var bc = Ti.Android.createBroadcastReceiver({
    onReceived: function() {
        Ti.API.info('Handling broadcast.');
    }
});

Ti.Android.registerBroadcastReceiver(bc, [Ti.Android.ACTION_VIEW]);
```

Comment: I think this feature is for titanium 3.1.0 , which is currently in beta stage. I am looking for an alternate solution. I prefer solution for below 2.x titanium version. Thanks

Comment: My latest effort is:
var activity = Ti.Android.currentActivity;
var args = activity.getIntent().getData();
Here arrs = "content://com.android.email.attachmentprovider/1/21/RAW". But I can't read content from this directory